# devise not set flash messages when dealing with ajax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

When user wants to perform an action that need him to login in first, devise will redirect him to the signin page and set a flash message: 'Please signin or signup before continue'. This works well with no-ajax request. But with an ajax request that also need signin first, it will  response with 401 error and we should handle it manually as follows:

```
$.ajax({                                            
url: '/books/user_score',                         
type: 'POST',                                     
data: { score: value, book_id: book_id },         
dataType: 'json',                                 
success: function(data) {                         
  bookStarWidget.data('starInfo', data.book_star);
  setVote(bookStarWidget);                        
  $("[name='my_vote']").rating('disable');        
},                                                
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
  if (jqXHR.status == 401) {                      
    window.location.assign('/users/sign_in');     
  }                                               
}                                                 
});
```

In the above code, we manually open the signin page when received the 401 error devise sends out. 
The problem is that there is NO flash message set in this way. So could someone knows how to set the flash message as usual to keep a consistent behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using javascript to set the location in the error case. Devise has a configuration option that will redirect on failure instead of returning http headers. This setting defaults to true which forces you to handle failure on xhr manually. Here's the explanation from the source: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/failure_app.rb#L120

So, in your Devise config:

```
config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false
```

Try the unauthenticated ajax request again and Devise will do the redirect for you, which should set up the flash messages as you expect.

Comment: I set the config as you said. Yes, devise will perform a redirect to login page. BUT the ajax `success: function(data)` was also called(the `data`param is the whole login html page) with 200 status. So the currrent page remain the same and the login page did NOT showed. So how to make the success ajax callback only be called when the user really login at that time?